# Unix commands not working

Tags: mysql, .bash-profile

[image: Terminal screen]Recently been trying to install mysql and changed my bash_profile around a few times. My unix commands seem to be unresponsive to any of my commands. Need some help to get it back up and running.

When using terminal yesterday the **'samuel-sosina-iMac'** did not appear. it was just **kingsosina$**

Also managed to pull this information up if it helps

```
 Samuel-Sosinas-iMac:~ kingsosina$ locate .bash_profile
 /Users/kingsosina/.bash_profile
 /usr/local/Cellar/.bash_profile
 Samuel-Sosinas-iMac:~ kingsosina$ ls -la
 Samuel-Sosinas-iMac:~ kingsosina$ export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin

 **-rw-r--r--@  1 kingsosina  staff     40 13 Nov 11:47 .bash_profile
 -rw-r--r--   1 kingsosina  staff  12288 13 Nov 12:27 .bash_profile.swo
 -rw-r--r--   1 kingsosina  staff  12288 13 Nov 12:08 .bash_profile.swp**
```

Comment: log in as root. zap the bash_profile

Comment: Hi i'm fairly new to this. Could you please explain step by step. Thanks

Comment: login as superuser. rename the file. `su` and `mv` are your friends#

Comment: @ssosina: Telling an inexperienced user to become superuser is not necessarily good advice. @EdHeal: Try `/bin/mv .bash_profile .bash_profile.bak` and then logout and login again. Then edit `.bash_profile.bak`, and rename it back when you’ve fixed it.

Comment: Hi I managed to get it working again. How would I delete the .bash_profile.swo and .bash_profile.swp?

Comment: can you post the output of following command?echo $PATH